# How do I loop through div elments using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I was working on MVC project having a shopping cart. In my shopping cart, I wanted to loop through all products that are in the cart and display each individual item with its name, unit price, and quantity option. And I also wanted to show the subtotal of all the items, and when the user changes the quantity of any item, the subtotal should be updated accordingly. How can I achieve that? Thank you.
My situation seems like the code below.

```
<div id="product">
    <p id="price">100</p>
    <select id="quantity">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="product">
    <p id="price">200</p>
    <select id="quantity">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<p>display subtotal here</p>

    <div id="subTotal"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you are doing this right. Are you using HTML and jQuery and that's it?

Comment: Could you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: this is more like "please code it for me"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make some changes in HTML code.
Replace id with class and check this fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/6404/

```
$(".quantity").off("change").on("change", function(e){
var total = 0;
$(".quantity").each(function(index,elem){
total = total+ parseInt($(elem).val());
})
$("#subTotal").text(total);
//console.log(total);
})
```

Comment: my intention was to multiply the price and selected quantity of each product and sum the result and display it in "subTotal " div element.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why do you have the same id repeated?
And pls put the javascript file Herr as well